# Set width no higher than 100%

Tags: jquery

How do I set `width` so that it never goes higher than 100% based on a variable value?

```
var progBarValue = $(this).find('.days-due').text();

$(this).find('.bar').width(progBarValue +"%");
```

I need the `width` value to clamp to a maximum of 100%.

For Example: If progBarValue returns 250% the `width` will still just be 100%.

Comment: What have you tried? all you have to do is detect what `progBarValue` is and set it to `100` if it's greater than `100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to modify the variable itself since the width attribute can be >100%.

```
var progBarValue = $(this).find('.days-due').text();
progBarValue = progBarValue > 100 ? 100 : progBarValue;
$(this).find('.bar').width(progBarValue +"%");
```